# Copy specific columns from vertica database to postgres database using PSQL

Tags: postgresql, psql, pg-dump

was trying to copy whole data from vertica to postgres DB table. Vertica table has 10 column and postgres table 9 matching column, and one column from serial generator. Used below PSQL command but its throwing error.

```
  pg_dump -U username -h server_address -a -t table_to_copy source_db | psql target_db
```

is it possible to copy only specific i.e 9 columns from vertica to postgres?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporary table and restore all of the table into it. Then drop the unnecessary columns. Finally, transfer the data from the temporary table to the main table.